# macos python os screencapture : 'could not create image from window'

Tags: python, macos, screenshot

## env

macos 12.6.8
Apple Silicon
python3.9.6

## code

```py
import os
from Quartz import CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowListOptionAll


windowName = 'Code'

windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(
        kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID)

for window in windowList:
    if window["kCGWindowOwnerName"] == windowName and window["kCGWindowBounds"]["X"] > 0:
        windowId = window['kCGWindowNumber']
        print(windowId)
        os.system('screencapture -x -l {windowId} test.png')
```

## output:

```
3087
could not create image from window
```

Directly using commands is available at the terminal, but not on Python

Comment: What does the last line of your question mean, please? What Terminal commands do you use to find the `windowid`? Does the `windowid` printed by your Python code look correct? What error do you get if you try a screencapture with a grossly and obviously incorrect `windowid`?

Comment: The `windowId` is correct, and executing commands directly at the terminal can work properly

Comment: Did you see and try Kurtis's answer?

Comment: Is this question abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

Your `os.system()` call is running a command with a literal `{windowID}` string. Did you mean to use an f-string? That is: `os.system(f'screencapture -x -l {windowId} test.png')`? Beyond that observation I'll note that you should never use `os.system()` because the string you pass to it is interpreted by a shell. Which is always risky because if any of the interpolated values contain shell meta-characters (such as `{` and `}`) it won't do what you expect and could have unwanted side-effects.